# Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSessionRepositoryFilter'

Tags: spring

Spring security issue,

its working and deployed  windows wildfly 10.0 server.Same code war deploy on Linux based wildfly server system  it's gives error like

`Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./hiflyy" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./hiflyy: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSessionRepositoryFilter'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once. Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSessionRepositoryFilter'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSessionRepositoryFilter'. Check to ensure the Filter is only configured once."}}`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
In my case it was caused by a spring boot app deployed on a tomcat as war file.

I followed this spring-session [tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/index.html#httpsession-jdbc)  and added the following class to my code as it was running in a servlet container:

```
 public class Initializer extends AbstractHttpSessionApplicationInitializer { 

    public Initializer() {
        super(Config.class); 
    }
 }
```

Additionally I had a configuration class annotated with

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession 
public class Config {...}
```

This led to the behaviour where spring tried to register the `springSessionRepositoryFilter` twice.

After I removed the `Initializer` class the problem was gone.